# How is the weighted fractional uptime of a Tor relay calculated?

Tags: relays

How is the weighted fractional uptime of a Tor relay calculated?

[Arma's "The lifecycle of a new relay"
post](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay) mentions
this statistic but does not describe it in detail:

> Directory authorities assign the Guard flag to relays based on three
>   characteristics: "bandwidth" (they need to have a large enough consensus
>   weight), "weighted fractional uptime" (they need to be working most of the
>   time), and "time known" (to make attacks more expensive, we don't want to
>   give the [Guard flag](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/dir-spec.txt#l1685) to relays that haven't been around a while first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [Tor spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n1937):

> **To calculate weighted fractional uptime:**
>
> compute the fraction of time
> that the router is up in any given day, weighting so that downtime and
> uptime in the past counts less.
>
> A node is 'familiar' if 1/8 of all active nodes have appeared more
> recently than it, OR it has been around for a few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I explained requirements for the Guard flag, including weighted fractional uptime, in the tech report [An Analysis of Tor Relay Stability](https://research.torproject.org/techreports/relay-stability-2011-06-30.pdf) in June 2011:

> "A router is a possible ‘Guard’ [if it is ‘familiar’,] if its Weighted Fractional Uptime is at least the median for ‘familiar’ active routers [or its Weighted Fractional Uptime is at least 98 %], and if its [advertised] bandwidth is at least median [of all active routers] or at least 250KB/s. [...] A node is ‘familiar’ if 1/8 of all active nodes have appeared more recently than it, or it has been around for [a weighted time of 8 days]."
>
> [...]
>
> The WFU metric measures the fraction of uptime of a relay in the past. [...] WFU values are discounted by factor 0.95 every 12 hours [...] including the current uptime session.